# Swift Request Data from JSON Api

Tags: json, swift, api, callback, alamofire

I tried to make a function that get corresponding from a json api, but the function returns the value faster than the alamofire request... Could someone help me on that? Thank you very much. Code is below.

```
func trainNameToTelecode(trainName: String) -> String {
    var returnTelecode: String = ""
    Alamofire.request("http://tra.ink/api/query/train?name=\(trainName)").responseJSON { (response) in
        let result = response.result
        guard let resultDict = result.value as? Dictionary<String,AnyObject> else {return}
        guard let bodyDict = resultDict["body"] as? [String:AnyObject] else {return}
        returnTelecode = bodyDict["telecode"] as! String
    }
    return returnTelecode
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a completion handler that will return you the string when your request is completed, for example:

```
func trainNameToTelecode(trainName: String, completion: (String) -> Void) {
    Alamofire.request("http://tra.ink/api/query/train?name=\(trainName)").responseJSON { (response) in
        let result = response.result
        guard let resultDict = result.value as? Dictionary<String,AnyObject> else {return}
        guard let bodyDict = resultDict["body"] as? [String:AnyObject] else {return}

        if let returnTelecode = bodyDict["telecode"] as? String {
            completion(returnTelecode)
        } else {
            completion("telecode is nil")
        }
    }
}

//and where you call your function:
self.trainNameToTelecode(trainName: "yourName") { (telecode) in
    print(telecode)
}
```